# Error: File format not recognised when setup Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

My C Drive is nearly full so I want to move all the data of coding into D drive. I have changed the bin path, move all the file about vscode from C drive to D. But when I try to run a test in C++ on vscode it notices like this:
[image: the error I got when try to run a test]

I think the problem is somewhere here although I have moved all file from C drive to D drive but when run vscode it still run file on C drive like this:
[image]
Does anyone know why? Please help me out, thank you so so much!

Comment: Simply moving an installed executable is usually a bad move. You'd need to reinstall it on the new drive. But before doing that, the error message is quite clear, and not addressed. Does `D:\Hello World\test.exe` exist? If it does, did you actually compile it to be debuggable? If you did, have you checked the permissions on it? Finally, do not store your code in a path with spaces. Some would say to generally not do it, but for me it depends on how it's interacted with. Definitely don't do it for code.

Comment: Also, you don't "run a test" by debugging the code. You simply run it after compiling it. I don't know how this became a thing, mishandling the debugger, but it really needs to stop.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).